# How can I set the validity of an ng-model in a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have this oversimplified directive for getting a phone number, and I want the ng-model to be invalid if the phone number is less than 10 digits.  I was testing out $setValidity but it's not says that is not a function.

```
angular.module('valkyrie').directive('phonenumber', function(){

return{
scope: {phonemodel: '=model'},
template: '<input ng-model="inputValue" type="tel" class="form-control">',
link: function(scope, element, attributes){
  scope.$watch('inputValue', function(value, oldValue) {
    value = String(value);
    var number = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    scope.phonemodel = number;
    scope.phonemodel.$setValidity('phone', false);
    console.log(scope.phonemodel);
  });
},
}
});
```

Comment: I think you need `{ require: 'ngModel' }` and then the ngModelController will become an element of the array of controllers that become the 4th argument to the link function when require is specified. Then you would call $setValidity on that. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726735/angular-setvalidity-not-working

Comment: Hmm, what exactly do you mean by "ng-model invalid". Do you mean, you want the input validated? If so, there's a few ways to do that, but probably the most "angularish" 1.x way would be to use a "filter". If you search for "angular js filter phone number", a few examples come up. I might not be understanding why you'd want to "invalidate" a model. Filters can be used in both markup and code-behind, and are a good way to check and reject values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Aluan Haddad mentioned in the comments, you need to require the `ngModel` directive within your directive. That will give you access to the `ngModelController`, and then you can just do `ngModelController.$setValidity`.

See a working demo here: http://codepen.io/miparnisari/pen/LxPoVw.

```
angular.module('valkyrie', [])
  .controller('parent', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phone = '';
})
  .directive('phonenumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<input ng-model="inputValue" type="tel" class="form-control">',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch('inputValue', function(value, oldValue) {
        if (!value) return;
        scope.ngModel = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
        if (scope.ngModel.length < 10)
          ctrl.$setValidity('phoneLength', false);
        else
          ctrl.$setValidity('phoneLength', true);
      });
    },
  };
});
```